# Batch File - Recursively check folders and move files

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a windows batch file that will scan a folder with many sub folders. Each sub folder can contain many files. I need the script to check if a sub folder contains over a certain number of files, and if it does move half of the files to a new folder with the same name but with a number at the end.

Example:

```
Main folder
-Subfolderone
-Subfoldertwo
-Subfolderthree
```

If Subfoldertwo contains over a certain number of files, lets say 1000, then half of the files within Subfoldertwo will be moved to Subfoldertwo(2), and so on for each sub folder.

```
Main folder
-Subfolderone
-Subfoldertwo
-Subfoldertwo(2)
-Subfolderthree
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET limit=5
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\*"') DO (
 SET /a newnum=2
 FOR /f %%c IN ('dir /b/a-d "%%~a" 2^>nul ^|find /c /v ""') DO IF %%c gtr %limit% CALL :process "%%a"
)
)

GOTO :EOF

:process
IF EXIST "%~1(%newnum%)\" SET /a newnum+=1&GOTO process
ECHO MD "%~1(%newnum%)"
FOR /f "skip=%limit%delims=" %%m IN ('dir /b /a-d "%~1"') DO ECHO MOVE "%~1\%%m" "%~1(%newnum%)\"

GOTO :eof
```

Simple enough. I've set the sourcedir to a constant for my testing and the limit to 5 for the same reason.

First build a list of the original diretory tree, then count the files in each directory. If that count is greater than the limit, process the directory.

In process, first find whether the proposed new directory already exists. If it does, keep incrementing the number 'til it doesn't.

Then list the filenames (only) from the original full-directoryname, skipping the first `%limit%` and for the remainder, move them to the new directoryname.

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

AND change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

---

Edit : revised for 'move half the files'

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET limit=5
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\*"') DO (
 SET /a newnum=2
 FOR /f %%c IN ('dir /b/a-d "%%~a" 2^>nul ^|find /c /v ""') DO IF %%c gtr %limit% SET /a nmove=%%c / 2&CALL :process "%%a"
)
)

GOTO :EOF

:process
IF EXIST "%~1(%newnum%)\" SET /a newnum+=1&GOTO process
ECHO MD "%~1(%newnum%)"
FOR /f "skip=%nmove%delims=" %%m IN ('dir /b /a-d "%~1"') DO ECHO MOVE "%~1\%%m" "%~1(%newnum%)\"

GOTO :eof
```

(simply calculate half of the count into `nmove` then skip that number instead)

Comment: this version is much better with explanation.

Comment: `IF EXIST "%~1(%newnum%)\" SET /a newnum+=1&GOTO process` nice++. I missed the forest for the trees.

Comment: Follow up question:  How would I just move half of the folder into the new folder if the file limit has been reached? I am new to batch and am having difficulty modifying the script. I tried calculating half the files by using the %%c var and dividing it by two and setting it to a new var that I use in the process function instead of the limit var but I can't figure out the syntax. batch is very confusing

Comment: @user1017063      please do not enhance questions. Simply make a new one.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was missing the & between setting the var and calling the function. Saved me a lot of manual work.

Answer (score 3):

you might test this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "StartFolder=X:\Main folder"
set /a MaxFiles=1000
cd /d "%StartFolder%"
:NewFolderCreated
set "NewFolderFlag="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /on') do call:process "%StartFolder%\%%~a"
if defined NewFolderFlag (goto:NewFolderCreated) else goto:eof

:process
SETLOCAL
cd "%~1"
for /f %%b in ('dir /b /a-d 2^>nul^|find /c /v ""') do set /a FileCount=%%b
if %FileCount% leq %MaxFiles% exit /b
set /a MoveCount=FileCount-MaxFiles
set "CurrentFolder=%~n1"
set "NextPath=%StartFolder%\%CurrentFolder%(2)%~X1"
echo("%CurrentFolder%"|findstr /re ".*([0-9][0-9]*)\"^">nul||goto:moving
set "BasePath=%CurrentFolder:~0,-1%"
:loop
if not "%BasePath:~-1%"=="(" set "FolderNo=%BasePath:~-1%%FolderNo%"&set "BasePath=%BasePath:~0,-1%"&goto:loop
set /a FolderNo+=1
set "NextPath=%StartFolder%\%BasePath%%FolderNo%)%~X1"
:moving
echo(Moving %MoveCount% files from "%~1" to "%NextPath%".
md "%NextPath%" 2>nul &&set "NewFolderFlag=true"
for /f "skip=%MaxFiles%delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /a-d /o-n') do move "%~1\%%~b" "%NextPath%" >nul
endlocal &set "NewFolderFlag=%NewFolderFlag%"
exit /b
```

Comment: batch is ugly. At least provide some comments for the newbie.

Comment: user1017063 is obviously a newbie. you give him this piece of ugly code he will just use it without knowing what's going on.

Comment: @brianadams I give him a working script. guess he not want to learn ugly batch.